# SQL Server 2008 - Alter column to Varchar from Float produces Scientific Notation

Tags: sql, sql-server, varchar, scientific-notation

I am having to change one of the columns in table which currently is Float to Varchar, but when I use alter command, it stores some of the longer numbers in Scientific Notation.

Can I avoid this?

If not, is there a way to easily update the table later to store the scientific notation as normal integer?

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you add a new varchar column and update it by casting the floats as varchars?

Comment: I get the result in Scientific notation when I do  `CAST(ColumnName AS VARCHAR(100))`

Comment: This question has been answered before.



http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server

Comment: Can you change the column to a numeric type first, like bigint or decimal(38,19), and then change it to varchar?

Comment: It works but again has same effect as the answers below. bigint removes everything after decimal points, and decimal causes trailing zeroes. I don't want the trailing zeroes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the link

[convert float into varchar in SQL server without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation)

You can cast the float to varchar(max)

[How to convert float to varchar in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server)

Comment: I am marking this as answer, but I found Anon's comment very helpful. I initially converted my data to decimal(38,19) and then used an update statement to remove the trailing zeroes. `Update MyTable
SET MyColumn = LEFT(MyColumn,CHARINDEX('.',MyColumn) - 1)
where  CAST(SUBSTRING(MyColumn, CHARINDEX('.',MyColumn),LEN(MyColumn)-1) AS float) = 0`

Answer (score 0):

I have a workaround for this I have used in the past. Dan isn't far off, but just casting it won't work. You can alter the table by adding a new varchar column then using str and ltrim to update the new column from the old float column. Say your varchar column was varchar(50), use something like:

update YourTable set NewColumn = ltrim(str(OldColumn, 50))

str() converts to character data, ltrim() gets rid of any extra blanks on the left. You can then always get rid of the old column. Feels janky but should work for you.

Comment: This works only for integer as anything after decimal point is lost.