# Inconsistant results when convert a float column type to nvarchar(250)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a column of type `float`, which I want to convert to to be of type `nvarchar(250)`, to make this column more dynamic and allow any set of characters.

So I want to convert it from being `float` to `nvarchar(250)`. But I need the following help:

1. Is this safe to do such a conversion & will it cause any data loss?
2. How can I write a database script to modify the column?

From my own testing, I found that some items which use to have a float value of `1302764` will have their value as "`1.30276e+006`" after changing the column type to be `nvarchar(250)`. Why would it do that?

Comment: For how to do this, please see...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server

Comment: but from my understanding is that nvarchar can contain any characters such as numbers, alphabetical , special characters, etc.. so why i got 1.30276e+006 when i convert 1302764 ??? as 1302764 can be inside an nvarchar ,, is this correct ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation

Comment: What code did you use to do the conversion? A number/float when being printed/displayed obviously has to fit to a physical format on a screen/paper so depending on the cast you did, it may have needed to use the exponential format. Did you use STR() ...https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx

Comment: @Will i did not use any code i just chnage the column type using sql management studio ...

Comment: @johnG please try to update the original float column using the STR() function.This is a similar question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20102294/sql-server-2008-alter-column-to-varchar-from-float-produces-scientific-notatio

Answer (score 0):

1.

SQL server will convert your data, **BUT** problems can occur with stored procedures or non-materialized views that are using the float column. Imagine some code like this:

> float myresult -> "Our float variable in stored proc"
>   float1 =
>   "select float_column from table where value = x" -> "1.23"
>   float2 =
>   "select float_column from table where value = y" -> "2.46"
>   myresult =
>   float1 + float2 -> "3.69"

In worst case SQL server will give you an error (e.g. "Cannot use operator + on NVARCHAR) or "myresult" will be converted to nvarchar which would give you the result "1.232.46" (string concat)

In the best case SQL server will convert the nvarchar to float implicitly.

Please check if stored procs or small programs are using the fields!

2.

```
alter table **TableName** 
alter column **ColumnName** nvarchar(250)
```

edit:
As mentioned before use STR() -> [convert float into varchar in SQL server without scientific notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521354/convert-float-into-varchar-in-sql-server-without-scientific-notation)