# converting float to varchar sql

Tags: sql, type-conversion

Im writing a stored procedure that will convert float columns to varchar as part of its process when returning the data.

i dont want to convert everything to varchar(max) bec i think its probably more efficient not to. what is the largest size varchar i need to use -

convert(NVARCHAR(????), floatcolumn)

100?

i want to make sure i never get a result that looks like 8397Xe10

Comment: I think you'd be safe with varchar(200) or so.  What are the odds you're going to be converting a 200 digit float?!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are using SQL Server (based on the code in your question).  If you don't want exponential notation, then use the `str()` function (documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189527.aspx)).  The length of the string doesn't have a large impact on performance, but you can do something like:

```
select str(floatcolumn, 100, 8) -- or whatever you think reasonable bounds are for your data
```