# Convert float 8.07 to string as 08:07 in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, sql-server-2005, date-conversion

I want to convert the float time field `8.07` to string `08:07`. Is there any easy way to do this?
Or Should I split it by dot, calculate the length and append zero accordingly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server  - SELECT STR(float_field, 25, 5)

Comment: There is no direct way to get desire result. you must need to implement string manipulation operation on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this:

```
DECLARE @value DECIMAL(9,2) = 8.07

SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(@value  + 1000000, 5), '.', ':');
```

Of course you can change the value you are adding to something small.

Comment: Amazingly amazing. I was getting mad :) wring a long (yes, very long) function to do this. And you did this in one line. Also the input float value will be just 8 for time 08:00 AM and for 12:00 AM its just blank, because it is 0.

Comment: Nice, then you add `100` instead of  `1000000`. I guess it won't change the performance but it will look more simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
DECLARE @t FLOAT = 8.073

SELECT @t AS t,
       ROUND(@t, 2) AS trunc_t, 
       REPLACE(RIGHT('00' + CAST(ROUND(@t, 2) AS VARCHAR(5)), 5), '.', ':') AS time_t
```

to get:

```
t      trunc_t  time_t
---------------------
8.073  8.07     08:07
```