# Cast FLOAT to NVARCHAR - different number of decimal places

Tags: t-sql

Query:

```
SELECT CAST('123.1234' AS FLOAT) AS 'Float value', CAST(CAST('123.1234' AS FLOAT) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'Text value'
```

returns:

```
Float value Text value
123,1234    123.123
```

Why there is a difference in number of decimal places?

[image: TSQL Query]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert float to varchar in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server)

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: tsql is sql-server @HABO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

When expression is float or real, style can be one of the values shown in the following table. Other values are processed as 0.

- 0 (default)  A maximum of 6 digits. Use in scientific notation, when appropriate.
- 1   Always 8 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
- 2    Always 16 digits. Always use in scientific notation.
- 3    Always 17 digits. Use for lossless conversion. With this style, every distinct float or real value is guaranteed to convert to a distinct character string. Applies to: Azure SQL Database, and starting in SQL Server 2016.
- 126, 128, 129    Included for legacy reasons and might be deprecated in a future release.

**the below code will give you the required result**

```
    SELECT CAST('123.1234' AS FLOAT) AS 'Float value', convert(nvarchar(max),CAST('123.1234' AS FLOAT) ,128 ) AS 'Text value'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get text back out of a number with scale you need to use numeric or decimal types and include the 'scale' second value of how much scale you want to weigh.  Float I believe only will do an estimation and for more precise estimation you need to use it.

```
Declare @Text varchar(16) = '123.1234'

SELECT 
  CAST(@Text AS FLOAT) AS 'Float value'
, CAST(CAST(@Text AS Float) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'float'
, CAST(CAST(@Text AS Float(4)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'float with precision'
, CAST(CAST(@Text AS numeric(8,4)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'numeric with precision'
, CAST(CAST(@Text AS decimal(8,4)) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS 'decimal with precision'
```

More number data types: https://academy.vertabelo.com/blog/understanding-numerical-data-types-sql/

Comment: Thanks for reply, but in case the number of decimal places is not the same every time the result will have 4 decimal places always.

Comment: Then you would use numeric or decimal with a 'scale' of 4 like numeric(8,4) or decimal(8,4).  You are using a type that is not meant to be highly precise and then wanting four point scale out of it.  Like the accepted answer says the answer to get what you want may be deprecated.  I would also stay away from things like 'text' type in code as well.