# Set SQL Server Management Studio to import numbers as non-float types

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In SQL Server if you convert `float` format data directly to `varchar` or `nvarchar` you get scientific notation garbage, as described in this question: [How to convert float to varchar in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server)

Which I work around using: `cast(cast([Fieldname] as numeric(18,0)) as varchar)`

Which is fine, but if I forget to do that it can cause invisible errors when comparing or joining, particularly if I let SQL Server do the conversion implicitly in my query.

I never set anything that's a whole number to `float` intentionally, but SSMS imports number data as `float` by default when you use the import/export wizard. I know you can change it manually each time you import (or if you use SSIS you can set batches that way but I don't have access to SSIS).

So is there a way to change SSMS's default import types globally so it sets number fields to `numeric` by default?

Comment: SSIS import / export wizard is not SSMS, and SSMS is not the sql engine. it doesn't sound like you're using any of the functionality in SSMS to import data. The short answer is NO, you can't change the SSIS Wizard's default setup. You can create the object via SSMS in the destination database and with the creation of the table set the correct datatypes, then point the SSIS Wizard to that object, which will inherit the datatype you set.

Comment: @Random_User so when you launch the wizard in SSMS it should be referred to as the SSIS wizard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ends up being to approach this differently. I had been letting the Import/Export wizard create a new table when I import data, in which scenario the data are imported in formats determined automatically.

If I instead have the Import/Export wizard append rows to an existing table the data are imported into whatever format the existing table uses for the relevant fields, i.e. the formats that I set when creating the table. Doing it this way removes any danger of importing in the wrong format.