# Convert float to varchar in SQL and remove the value after decimal

Tags: sql, nvarchar

I have table contains brand ID looks like the below:
BrandID is stored as float.

```
| BrandID | 
| -------- | 
| 1000962.000000   | 
| 1000565.000000   |
```

How can I convert this brand ID into varchar(11) and remove the value after .(dot)
What I want is:

```
| BrandID  | 
| -------- | 
| 1000962  | 
| 1000565  |
```

I tried
`SELECT CAST([brand ID] AS Varchar)` but failed and get another error
String or binary data would be truncated.
How to remove the value after . and then convert it to varchar?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert float to varchar in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715675/how-to-convert-float-to-varchar-in-sql-server)

Comment: Please add the tag of the database you are using to your question.

Comment: Doesn't Varchar mean varchar(1)? You need a longer target!

Comment: Ideally you should change the column to int. Also it looks more like a decimal column, not float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert `float` to `int` first, then convert it again to `nvarchar`.

try this:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST([BrandID] AS INT) AS NVARCHAR)
```